# Sidekiq::Cron::Job throw me uninitialized constant Rufus::Scheduler::CronLine error

Tags: rufus-scheduler, ruby-on-rails-5.2, sidekiq-cron

I am using Ruby on Rails 5.2.0 to develop a system and I need to run a job every 2 minute. 
I'm using `sidekiq` for background processing and `sidekiq-cron` for scheduling jobs.

I execute the following line in rails console:

```
job=Sidekiq::Cron::Job.new( name: 'TestWorker_Job', cron: '*/2 * * * *', klass: 'PriceWorker')
```

And this is the answer

```
=> #<Sidekiq::Cron::Job:0x000055b6d54707e8
@active_job=false,
@active_job_queue_name_delimiter=nil,
@active_job_queue_name_prefix=nil,
@args=[],
@cron="*/2 * * * *",
@fetch_missing_args=true,
@klass="PriceWorker",
@last_enqueue_time=nil,
@message={"retry"=>false, "queue"=>"default", "class"=>"PriceWorker",   "args"=>[]},
@name="TestWorker_Job",
@queue="default",
@queue_name_with_prefix="default",
@status="enabled">
```

But it throws me an error:

```
job.errors
=> ["'cron' -> */2 * * * *: uninitialized constant Rufus::Scheduler::CronLine"]
```

There is no valid job. I don't know what i am doing wrong. [Sidekiq-cron github page](https://github.com/ondrejbartas/sidekiq-cron#adding-cron-job) do the same thing.

Comment: Before posting here, please check the project's issue tracker. You'll find answers at https://github.com/ondrejbartas/sidekiq-cron/issues/199

Answer (score 8):

sidekiq-cron is not targeting the correct version of rufus-scheduler. To make it work again, add this to your `Gemfile`:

```
gem 'rufus-scheduler', '~> 3.4.0'
```

Then run `$ bundle install rufus-scheduler`.

Comment: Rufus-scheduler is using semantic versioning. Sidekiq-cron was using a "behind the scene" rufus-scheduler feature that changed in the newer versions. Also sidekiq-cron was depending on rufus-scheduler ">= 3.3.0" instead of the classical "~> 3.3", it was bound for such an issue. Rufus-scheduler has not to be compatible to a downstream project, it's the other way around.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I changed the text. Please change your downvote, as the solution does work.

Comment: Done. Thanks a lot!